# Jenkins build - How to retain the build history while reseting build version to 1

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I want to change build number each release and it should start with build number 1 such as 
1.0.1, 1.0.2 and so on - Release
2.0.1, 2.0.2 and so on - Release

I'm using following two plug-ins to have build version as 1.0.1

- **Build Name Setter Plugin:** https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Build+Name+Setter+Plugin
- **Next Build Number Plugin:** https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Next+Build+Number+Plugin

Currently, I need to cleanup old build before changing the version from 1.0.100 to 2.0.1 and I loose build histories and no longer available on jenkins dashboard.

All available plug-ins just set the build display name not the actual build version.

Is there any plug-in which can keep track of major minor version and also maintain the build history?

Comment: The *Jenkins* Build Number is just an incrementing integer. It's unsuited for anything other than to track Job Builds within Jenkins. Treat it like a database ID column and stay happier. If your software has any numbering, primarily keep track of that numbering in your SCC! (Git tags, whatever)